# Trying to center a rotated label inside a background image

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        // Create the background image view
        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cardStock1"))
        backgroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
        backgroundImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        backgroundImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        backgroundImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
        view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            backgroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    
        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label1.text = "Hello World"
        label1.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 55)
        label1.textColor = .gray
        label1.rotate(degrees: -7)
        view.addSubview(label1)
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            label1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            label1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            label1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160)
        ])
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func rotate(degrees: CGFloat) {
        rotate(radians: CGFloat.pi * degrees / 180.0)
    }

    func rotate(radians: CGFloat) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)
        self.layoutIfNeeded() // Update layout after rotation
    }
}
```

Running this code, the label is not centered within the image. How can i adjust the code appropriately.

Thanks for the reply. This code change results in this image:

[image]

Comment: The code you posted does not result in the image you posted. This is what I see with your code as-is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzfIZ.png This is what I get if I change your `backgroundImage` to `300x300`, centered in the view... and the label constrained centerX/Y to the `backgroundImage`... and the label set to `label1.textAlignment = .center`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTFtZ.png

Answer (score 1):

To centre the label you need to update the constraints for the label, currently you set the constraints set the centre of the label to the centre of the view. To centre the label within the image, you can update the constraints as follows,

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    label1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundImage.centerXAnchor),
    label1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundImage.centerYAnchor),
    label1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
    label1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160)
])
```